# Signal delivery system for routers

Tags: networking, ssh

My network have one server and many routers (around 300 and will be more, all working on OpenWRT). Routers don't have public IP and server can not connect to them. But i need to know that routers is online. For it, once in minute routers send a signal to the server.

It's signal:

```
wget http://server.com/ping?mac=MACOFTHEROUTER
```

And when receiver written in PHP get query from router, merely save date and mac address of the router in database. Now we know that router is alive or when it had disabled.

If i want to send something command to the router i put my command to answer of receiver and this result will save in file on the router, after file get permission to run, after run it and delete it. And send another signal to the router that mission completed, also by wget, but to different URL.

```
 wget http://server.com/done?mac=MACOFTHEROUTER&result=Stout+of+the+command
```

Now server know result of the command and can display it to user. It's working for me good. But sometime result of the command very big and i can't put it in the GET. Also after send a command i should waiting for one a minute for get result and send next. It's not good if you try to debug routers. And i want to send one command to all routers in one time and get answer from all. It's ideal situation. For this i think i can use something streaming (real-time) applications that for example using in web technology. Like http://pusher.com/. I want something like this for my network to allow view status of the routers in real-time and send a commands to the routers also in real-time. Of course that does not load the network and should be secure. Help please for search better solution. Also apologize for my english.

Comment: You probably want a proper network monitoring system instead of this cludge.

Comment: BTW, I sure hope you are planning on doing this over https, and not http.  It would be trivial to intercept and modify your http requests/replies, and if your router is running commands based on this I would basically own your routers.

Comment: Sounds more like a software development question than a system administration question.

Answer (score 1):

Is the hardware sufficient that you could install puppet or another agent-based configuration management tool?  The puppet client can be configured to periodically check in, and when it checks in it will report lots of useful facts to the puppet server which can be captured stored, and used in many useful ways.  This is almost certainly the correct and standard way to do what yo want.  But most of the popular configuration management tools take a lot of resources.

If that isn't an option can you setup a simple VPN client on all the routers that will make establish and keep a connection open to a monitoring system.  Don't route anything over the VPN, just use it for a point to point connection to the management system.  From there you could just SSH out to all the connected nodes.

If you want to stick to your http request setup, then you might want to look at curl instead.  With CURL it is very easy to send a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you doing yourself a favor and stop reinventing the wheel. Proper monitoring systems such as [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/), [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) allows you to monitor your routers & other hardware. At least Zabbix also has mechanisms for monitoring hard-to-reach targets behind the firewalls for example with [Zabbix proxies](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/distributed_monitoring/proxies)

Installing them is easy and in addition to simple "Is this target responding to ping?" you can monitor & graph trends about disk space usage, CPU usage, server load, test if services are actually working, send out alerts via e-mail/SMS/IM/whatever in case something goes wrong... there are no excuses for the lack of an actual monitoring.